# Fill a section multiple time in a PDF form iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iTextSharp to fill a form from a PDF template. I fill data to form by mapping the field names.
But the PDF form template  have a section containing 4 text fields and one radio input field. This section need to be repeted multiple times in the form.

So my question here is that how can I create this section multiple times on the bases of data available.

Please help.

Comment: If you repeat the section multiple times,  you'll also repeat the values multiple times. Is that desired?

Comment: yes, I have multiple entities that i need to populate to pdf

Comment: *I have multiple entities* - and for each of them you want to show the identical values?

Comment: yes, for each entity there will be a separate section of 4 text field and one radio input

Comment: That section is a separate page?

Comment: No, It is a small section. a page can have 3 section

Comment: As I google I found that there are two type of pdf forms AcroForm-based and XFA forms. Do i need XFA form for it

Comment: While XFA can model such dynamic form parts, the person who prepared your `PDF template` must have properly designed the XFA form. Furthermore iTextSharp will only help you extracting the existing XFA XML definition and later on re-inserting a manipulated XFA XML; you'll have to edit the XML in your own code. And last but not least, XFA is going to be deprecated in PDF-2.0.

Comment: Using AcroForm PDFs you'll have to rename the fields for each additional section copy beyond the first, and iTextSharp supports your use case with a high level API only if that section is a page by itself. Otherwise you'll have to work with its lower level APIs which requires you to have some intimate knowledge of the PDF specification.